# Read Data from .property file from Jenkins and Parse Using Shell Script

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, jenkins, devops

Let Say i have a .properties file saved in Jenkins Which looks like

```
standardelectric_guest_plp
ladedanlar_employeelogin_checkout
```

I First need to read all datas in the File

And next i need to parse data using the separator using the file, Like

```
Websites=standardelectric,ladedanlar
User=guest,employeelogin
Page=plp,Checkout
```

Is there any way we can acheive this using shell or Any other way we can do it in Jenkins itself. These above parameter will be inputs to my Automation Scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Websites="$(awk -F '_' '{print $1}' .properties | paste -d, -s)"
User="$(awk -F '_' '{print $2}' .properties | paste -d, -s)"
Page="$(awk -F '_' '{print $3}' .properties | paste -d, -s)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-7) cmdlet for this:

```
$File = @'
standardelectric_guest_plp
ladedanlar_employeelogin_checkout
'@

$Data = $File | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter _ -Header Websites,User,Page
```

Grabbing your properties:

```
$Data.User                         #PowerSehll v3+
$Data | Select-Object -Expand User #PowerShell v2
```